# Hyperledger fabric chaincode upgrade

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have setup the hyper-ledger fabric network with 2 organisation, and have install the 
fabcar chain-code with version v1.1 on peer and i am keeping the storage of blockchain.

Next i added more methods on fabcar, Trying to upgrade the exist fabcar to v1.2, but i am facing the error.

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg cannot get package for chaincode (fabcar:1.2)

I am using the below command to upgrade the chaincode

```
peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n fabcar -v 1.2 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg cannot get package for chaincode
>   (fabcar:1.2)

Means your upgraded chaincode was not installed on peers.

Check Your chanincode installed on peers or not?

```
peer chaincode list --installed
```

In the output, You saw the only previous installed chaincode. So you have to **first package a chaincode** and then upgrade a chaincode.

```
 peer chaincode package ccpack.out -n fabcar -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/fabcar -v 1.2 -s -S
```

**peer chaincode signpackage example**

```
 peer chaincode signpackage ccwith1sig.pak ccwith2sig.pak
```

**Upgrade chaincode**

```
peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n fabcar -v 1.2 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

I recommend [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html?highlight=peer%20chaincode%20upgrade#peer-chaincode-upgrade-example) link to upgrade your fabric chaincode.

*Note: replace chaincode path with your chaincode path.*

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You first have to install the upgraded version of the chaincode by installing it as version 1.2. Then upgrade it as you were doing earlier.